# How to use triggers for cross table updating

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have three columns of data (A, B, C) in two tables (table_a, table_b) where I want to use a trigger that will update a column in `table_a` with concatenated column values from `table_a` and `table_b` anytime a record is updated in table_a.

```
CREATE TABLE 'table_a' 
(
    'id' BIGINT(50) NOT NULL,
    'A' VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    'B' VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    'C' VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    PRIMARYKEY ('id')
)

CREATE TABLE 'table_b' 
(
    'id' BIGINT(50) NOT NULL,
    'A' VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    'B' VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    'C' VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    PRIMARYKEY ('id')
)

INSERT INTO table_a (A, B, C) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO table_b (A, B, C) VALUES (4, 5, 6)
```

Without a trigger, I would use this statement to update table_a

```
UPDATE Table_a
SET table_a.A = COALESCE(table_a.B, 0) + ’,’ + COALESCE(table_b.A, 0)
FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE table_a.id = 1
```

After UPDATE

**table_a**:

```
| A    | B  | C  |
|------+----+----+
| 2, 4 | 2  | 3  |
```

This is my attempt at the trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER  update_table_a
ON table_a
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @id as BIGINT

    SELECT @id = id FROM updated

    UPDATE table_a
    SET table_a.A = COALESCE(table_a.B, 0) + ‘,’ + COALESCE(table_b.A, 0)
    FROM Table_a 
    INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
    WHERE table_a.id = @id
END
GO
```

My problem is that the value in table_a.A reverts back to its original value when I attempt to change the value in that column with this trigger in place.

Comment: First thing, NEVER use the following statements because the inserted table (there is no updated table) can have more than one record:  
SELECT @id = id FROM updated

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will contain 25 rows each. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @Id =`  just selects one non-deterministic row, and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** pseudo table called `updated` - in the case of an `UPDATE` trigger, you have `Deleted` with the old values (before the update happened), and `Inserted` with the new values after the update.

You need to use this **properly set-based** code to handle this update - you need to make use of the `Inserted` pseudo table which contains all the new values of the rows that have been updated (in `table_A`).

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_table_a
ON table_a
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_a
    SET A = COALESCE(i.B, 0) + ‘,’ + COALESCE(table_b.A, 0)
    FROM Table_a 
    INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON table_a.id = i.id
END
GO
```

Comment: And reason why your code was not updating the value in table_a when you made a change was that since there is no updated table, your @ID value was null, therefore no actual records were being updated by the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  This works.  I was being overly restrictive, not to mention using the wrong pseudo table reference.  Additional question.  What if the table being updated has several hundred thousand records that already match the values that would otherwise populate the value in table_a.A.  Can an "If" statement at the beginning of the trigger be included?

Comment: @JRP: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.